# Rails 3 + Meta_Search custom redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, meta-search

I am using meta_search gem and would like to display the search results on another page different from model/index. Is it possible to redirect to the view of my choice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call the search from whatever method you wanted with the params. Instead of:

```
def index
  @search = Article.search(params[:search])
  @articles = @search.all   # load all matching records
end
```

You might have

```
def show
  @search = Article.search(params[:search])
  @articles = @search.where(:user_id => params [:user_id]).all   # load all matching records
end
```

Depending on the custom [Where](http://erniemiller.org/projects/metasearch/#customizing) you created

Comment: Ok. But my search form is in the application layout, so I have to a filter on app controller to index movies:`def index_movies
    @search = Movie.search(params[:search])
    @movies = @search.all
  end`        Am I just taking the wrong approach?  (sorry I can't format!)

Comment: Your search is in `application.html.erb`?

Comment: Yes, I have a partial '/movies/search' that is rendered in application.html.erb

Comment: Ahhh... then graywh's solution or a variation of it is probably better to pursue

Answer (score 0):

If you want the search action to use a different route, give a `url` option to `form_for`.

`<%= form_for @search, :url => search_results_movies_path do |f| %>`

Comment: Mmmh, I have this on my application layout:                                                                `<%= form_for @search, search_results_movies_path  do |f|  %>
    <%= f.text_field :title_or_actors_or_director_contains, :class=>"span2" %>
    <input id="Submit" class="btn pull-right" type="submit" value="Buscar" name="Submit">
<% end %>     `                                                                                                                 Now, if i start the search while in a different controller than 'movies', It doesn't redirect to the search results. Can I fix this?

Comment: @fertech You have to pass the url in through the options hash like so `<%= form_for @search, :url => search_results_movies_path do |f| %>`